# Why is CMake inserting quotes into compile options that have spaces?

Tags: cmake

I have compile options in list form like:

```
set(flags "-auto" "-qopenmp" "-convert big_endian")
```

Then, I add them to the target:

```
  target_compile_options(${lib_name} PRIVATE ${flags})
```

But when I run "make" the compile options with spaces get quotes added to them:

```
-auto -qopenmp "-convert big_endian"
```

And then the compiler doesn't recognize it as a flag.

So, why does CMake add quotes to my compile options? Is there any way I can stop it from doing that?

Comment: Is it a *requirement* that your flags be in list form? Why not just set them all (without the quotes) in the `target_compile_options()` command?

Answer (score 1):

Found the fix.

Just have to also quote the option to the flag like so:

```
"-convert" "big_endian"
```

Comment: CMake did exactly what you requested. You wanted to pass `-convert big_endian` string as a command line parameter. Quotes are required to make parameter parser treat this string as a single parameter. Other parameters do not have quotes because these are single-worded.

Comment: And now you can rewrite your CMake code as `set(flags -auto -qopenmp -convert big_endian)`.